# SoftEther Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: vpn, local-area-network, tunneling, softether

I have already already setup a Site-to-Site connection via the SoftEther bridge package. (Please see attached diagram).

I enabled SecureNAT on the central server, and to avoid conflict with my local router’s DHCP, I had the SecureNAT’s ip range set from 192.168.0.202 - 220

The default gateway of the SecureNAT is 192.168.0.201

I can ping 192.168.0.201 from one of the laptops on the digram, and I receive a ping from the server. This tells that the connection was successful.

However, I want to channel all my traffic from one of those laptops through the SecureNAT.

I’m not sure what the best way to do this is. I tried establishing a VPN connection to the central server via its LOCAL ip address “192.168.0.201”. This didn’t work. The server didn’t respond.

But I can connect to the central server via its public IP address.

The reason I want to use the local IP address to establish the VPN connection is because direct L2TP connections from within China to abroad is often disrupted. However, the bridge connection is much more stable and I want to utilize this to in effect wrap my L2TP connection in.

Is this possible?

[image]